# Pass variable to input text field in a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

Good morning, I need your help. I am using the code below, where I have a table with colors and clicking on the desired color, opens a modal and the input text is filled with the desired color.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#myModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                   var color = $(e.relatedTarget).data('number');
                    $(this).find('#inputColor').val(color);                       
                });
            });
```

It turns out that when using the code above, if the page is loaded for the first time, the value comes null when I click the desired color to go to the modal. On the second try, it works. I've been there for days and I will not solve it.

Comment: Try use `$(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-number');`

Comment: Show your `HTML` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to change your code a bit and use:

> var color = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-number');